# Android App Bundle: Google Play 150MB limit for xamarin project

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Problem: When uploading my .aab to google, I'm told that certain configurations will result in a build over the 150MB limit.

i have tried in project cleared obj and bin files and clean the solution.

Comment: Which linker setting are you using? Maybe set the linking behavior to "Link SDK Libraries" or try "Link All". Do you have a lot of static assets like images, and so on?

Comment: For large Android app, See Google Play's [Play Asset Delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery). I'm not sure how to use that with Xamarin.Android, but there must be some way.

Comment: The limit on 150 MB is on the download size at installation time. For application that require more than 150MB, there will be other solutions, which are called PAD. You can read more about [Play Asset Delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery) and [Xamarin.Android Asset Delivery](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/xamarinandroid-asset-delivery/1527043).